# pyparsing generates empty railroad HTML file in some cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I have been using pyparsing 3.0.0a2 to generate railroads (the versions 3.0.0b generates only horizontal diagrams as it seems the `vertical` parameter doesn't have any effect, which is annoying).
The following code is using two expressions `sim` and `sim_expr` and I am trying to create the corresponding railroads as HTML files. **Note that I also would like to create the standalone SVG files for documentation but I am not sure how to do it. So if you have at least this information, please let me know in a comment.**

The results are two HTML files, `sim.html` contains a picture but the `sim_expr.html` is empty.

How can I solve the problem of an empty file?

```py
from pyparsing import *

LPAR, RPAR, COMMA, DOT, EQ, COLON = map(Suppress, "(),.=:")

sim_a = (Literal('1') ^ Literal('2'))('elm*') \
        + COMMA \
        + (Literal('a')
           ^ Literal('b')
           ^ Literal('c')
           ^ Literal('d'))
sim_b = (Literal('4') ^ Literal('5'))('elm*') \
        + COMMA \
        + (Literal('a')
           ^ Literal('b')
           ^ Literal('c')
           ^ Literal('d'))

sim = sim_a ^ sim_b

sim_expr = Group(Literal('sim')('directive')
                 + LPAR
                 + sim.setName('List')
                 + RPAR).setName('SIM')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '3.0.0b' in __version__:
        sim.create_diagram('sim.html')
        sim_expr.create_diagram('sim_expr.html')
    elif '3.0.0' in __version__:
        from pyparsing.diagram import to_railroad, railroad_to_html

        with open('sim.html', 'w') as fp:
            rr = to_railroad(sim)
            fp.write(railroad_to_html(rr))
        with open('sim_expr.html', 'w') as fp:
            rr = to_railroad(sim_expr)
            fp.write(railroad_to_html(rr))
```

---

### sim_expr.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
        <style type="text/css">
            .railroad-heading {
                font-family: monospace;
            }
        </style>
    
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

---

### sim.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
        <style type="text/css">
            .railroad-heading {
                font-family: monospace;
            }
        </style>
    
</head>
<body>


    <div class="railroad-group">
        <h1 class="railroad-heading">List</h1>
        <div class="railroad-description"></div>
        <div class="railroad-svg">
            <svg class="railroad-diagram" height="320" viewBox="0 0 457.0 320" width="457.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g transform="translate(.5 .5)">
<style>/* <![CDATA[ */
    svg.railroad-diagram {
        background-color:hsl(30,20%,95%);
    }
    svg.railroad-diagram path {
        stroke-width:3;
        stroke:black;
        fill:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
    svg.railroad-diagram text {
        font:bold 14px monospace;
        text-anchor:middle;
    }
    svg.railroad-diagram text.label{
        text-anchor:start;
    }
    svg.railroad-diagram text.comment{
        font:italic 12px monospace;
    }
    svg.railroad-diagram rect{
        stroke-width:3;
        stroke:black;
        fill:hsl(120,100%,90%);
    }
    svg.railroad-diagram rect.group-box {
        stroke: gray;
        stroke-dasharray: 10 5;
        fill: none;
    }

/* ]]> */
</style><g>
<path d="M20 45v20m10 -20v20m-10 -10h20"></path></g><g>
<path d="M40 55h0.0"></path><path d="M417.0 55h0.0"></path><path d="M40.0 55h20"></path><g>
<path d="M60.0 55h0.0"></path><path d="M397.0 55h0.0"></path><g>
<path d="M60.0 55h0.0"></path><path d="M221.5 55h0.0"></path><g>
<path d="M60.0 55h0.0"></path><path d="M145.5 55h0.0"></path><path d="M60.0 55h20"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M80.0 55h0.0"></path><path d="M125.5 55h0.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="80.0" y="44"></rect><text x="102.75" y="59">'1'</text></g><path d="M125.5 55h20"></path><path d="M60.0 55a10 10 0 0 1 10 10v10a10 10 0 0 0 10 10"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M80.0 85h0.0"></path><path d="M125.5 85h0.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="80.0" y="74"></rect><text x="102.75" y="89">'2'</text></g><path d="M125.5 85a10 10 0 0 0 10 -10v-10a10 10 0 0 1 10 -10"></path></g><path d="M145.5 55h10"></path><g>
<path d="M155.5 55h0.0"></path><path d="M221.5 55h0.0"></path><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="66" x="155.5" y="36"></rect><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M155.5 55h10.25"></path><path d="M211.25 55h10.25"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="165.75" y="44"></rect><text x="188.5" y="59">','</text></g><g class="non-terminal ">
<path d="M155.5 28h0.0"></path><path d="M221.5 28h0.0"></path><text class="comment" x="188.5" y="33">Suppress</text></g></g></g><path d="M221.5 55h10"></path><g>
<path d="M231.5 55h0.0"></path><path d="M397.0 55h0.0"></path><path d="M231.5 55h20"></path><g>
<path d="M251.5 55h0.0"></path><path d="M377.0 55h0.0"></path><path d="M251.5 55h20"></path><g>
<path d="M271.5 55h0.0"></path><path d="M357.0 55h0.0"></path><path d="M271.5 55h20"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M291.5 55h0.0"></path><path d="M337.0 55h0.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="291.5" y="44"></rect><text x="314.25" y="59">'a'</text></g><path d="M337.0 55h20"></path><path d="M271.5 55a10 10 0 0 1 10 10v10a10 10 0 0 0 10 10"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M291.5 85h0.0"></path><path d="M337.0 85h0.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="291.5" y="74"></rect><text x="314.25" y="89">'b'</text></g><path d="M337.0 85a10 10 0 0 0 10 -10v-10a10 10 0 0 1 10 -10"></path></g><path d="M357.0 55h20"></path><path d="M251.5 55a10 10 0 0 1 10 10v40a10 10 0 0 0 10 10"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M271.5 115h20.0"></path><path d="M337.0 115h20.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="291.5" y="104"></rect><text x="314.25" y="119">'c'</text></g><path d="M357.0 115a10 10 0 0 0 10 -10v-40a10 10 0 0 1 10 -10"></path></g><path d="M377.0 55h20"></path><path d="M231.5 55a10 10 0 0 1 10 10v70a10 10 0 0 0 10 10"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M251.5 145h40.0"></path><path d="M337.0 145h40.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="291.5" y="134"></rect><text x="314.25" y="149">'d'</text></g><path d="M377.0 145a10 10 0 0 0 10 -10v-70a10 10 0 0 1 10 -10"></path></g></g><path d="M397.0 55h20"></path><path d="M40.0 55a10 10 0 0 1 10 10v124a10 10 0 0 0 10 10"></path><g>
<path d="M60.0 199h0.0"></path><path d="M397.0 199h0.0"></path><g>
<path d="M60.0 199h0.0"></path><path d="M221.5 199h0.0"></path><g>
<path d="M60.0 199h0.0"></path><path d="M145.5 199h0.0"></path><path d="M60.0 199h20"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M80.0 199h0.0"></path><path d="M125.5 199h0.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="80.0" y="188"></rect><text x="102.75" y="203">'4'</text></g><path d="M125.5 199h20"></path><path d="M60.0 199a10 10 0 0 1 10 10v10a10 10 0 0 0 10 10"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M80.0 229h0.0"></path><path d="M125.5 229h0.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="80.0" y="218"></rect><text x="102.75" y="233">'5'</text></g><path d="M125.5 229a10 10 0 0 0 10 -10v-10a10 10 0 0 1 10 -10"></path></g><path d="M145.5 199h10"></path><g>
<path d="M155.5 199h0.0"></path><path d="M221.5 199h0.0"></path><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="66" x="155.5" y="180"></rect><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M155.5 199h10.25"></path><path d="M211.25 199h10.25"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="165.75" y="188"></rect><text x="188.5" y="203">','</text></g><g class="non-terminal ">
<path d="M155.5 172h0.0"></path><path d="M221.5 172h0.0"></path><text class="comment" x="188.5" y="177">Suppress</text></g></g></g><path d="M221.5 199h10"></path><g>
<path d="M231.5 199h0.0"></path><path d="M397.0 199h0.0"></path><path d="M231.5 199h20"></path><g>
<path d="M251.5 199h0.0"></path><path d="M377.0 199h0.0"></path><path d="M251.5 199h20"></path><g>
<path d="M271.5 199h0.0"></path><path d="M357.0 199h0.0"></path><path d="M271.5 199h20"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M291.5 199h0.0"></path><path d="M337.0 199h0.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="291.5" y="188"></rect><text x="314.25" y="203">'a'</text></g><path d="M337.0 199h20"></path><path d="M271.5 199a10 10 0 0 1 10 10v10a10 10 0 0 0 10 10"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M291.5 229h0.0"></path><path d="M337.0 229h0.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="291.5" y="218"></rect><text x="314.25" y="233">'b'</text></g><path d="M337.0 229a10 10 0 0 0 10 -10v-10a10 10 0 0 1 10 -10"></path></g><path d="M357.0 199h20"></path><path d="M251.5 199a10 10 0 0 1 10 10v40a10 10 0 0 0 10 10"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M271.5 259h20.0"></path><path d="M337.0 259h20.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="291.5" y="248"></rect><text x="314.25" y="263">'c'</text></g><path d="M357.0 259a10 10 0 0 0 10 -10v-40a10 10 0 0 1 10 -10"></path></g><path d="M377.0 199h20"></path><path d="M231.5 199a10 10 0 0 1 10 10v70a10 10 0 0 0 10 10"></path><g class="terminal ">
<path d="M251.5 289h40.0"></path><path d="M337.0 289h40.0"></path><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="45.5" x="291.5" y="278"></rect><text x="314.25" y="293">'d'</text></g><path d="M377.0 289a10 10 0 0 0 10 -10v-70a10 10 0 0 1 10 -10"></path></g></g><path d="M397.0 199a10 10 0 0 0 10 -10v-124a10 10 0 0 1 10 -10"></path></g><path d="M 417.0 55 h 20 m -10 -10 v 20 m 10 -20 v 20"></path></g></svg>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```